# Why when I set overflow property to hidden, then a pseudo element goes away?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```css
.user_inbox{
  position:absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius:2px;
  -o-border-radius:2px;
  -moz-border-radius:2px;
  -webkit-border-radius:2px;
  -ms-border-radius:2px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #ccc;
  -o-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #ccc;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #ccc;
  -ms-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #ccc;
  width:  310px;
  direction:ltr;
  left:53px;
  top:63px;
  border:1px solid #CCC;
  z-index:5000;
  height:100%;
  max-height:55%;
  min-height:180px; 
  right: 53px;
  top: 65px;
  /* overflow:hidden; */
}
.user_inbox:after{
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 2px 0 rgba( 178, 178, 178, .4 );
  -o-box-shadow: -2px 2px 2px 0 rgba( 178, 178, 178, .4 );
  -moz-box-shadow: -2px 2px 2px 0 rgba( 178, 178, 178, .4 );
  -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 2px 2px 0 rgba( 178, 178, 178, .4 );
  -ms-box-shadow: -2px 2px 2px 0 rgba( 178, 178, 178, .4 );
  content: "\00a0";
  display: block;
  height: 12px;
  width:  12px;
  margin-left:18px;
  position:absolute;
  top:-5px;
  transform:rotate(135deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(135deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(135deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(135deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(135deg);
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  right: 18px;
}

.title{
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  display:block;
  width; 100%;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="user_inbox">
  <span class="title">there is a title</span>
</div>
```

Now please remove that comment which is around this line: `overflow:hidden;` *(I mean please make that line uncomment)* .. then suddenly that up-arrow will be vanished.

Ok well, I need both that up-arrow and this property `overflow:hidden;`. How can I handle that?

Comment: You **cannot** expect a child or pseudo element to survive overflow-hidden. So clearly you need another layer of Element. *Tip of the day:* create an inner child element with overflow hidden.

Comment: The problem, as @RokoC.Buljan alluded to, is that the span itself has `overflow:hidden` on it. But the pseudo-element is shown _outside_ of the span element's bounding box. And anything outside of that box will be cut out; that's what `overflow:hidden` does. Could you tell us why you needed `overflow:hidden`? Maybe we can figure out another way of doing this.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Ok thanks .. Just one thing, Can I set `overflow:hidden` **only** for the bottom of the element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`overflow:hidden` is game-over for a child element trying to pop out of it's parent overflow boundary.
Instead create an inner container that will overflow (hidden)

```css
.overflow{
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  background: #cf5;
}

.user_inbox{
  position:absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius:2px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #ccc;
  width:  310px;
  direction:ltr;
  left:53px;
  top:63px;
  border:1px solid #CCC;
  z-index:5000;
  height:100%;
  max-height:55%;
  min-height:180px; 
  right: 53px;
  top: 65px;
}
.user_inbox:after{
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 2px 0 rgba( 178, 178, 178, 0.4 );
  content: "\00a0";
  display: block;
  height: 12px;
  width:  12px;
  margin-left:18px;
  position:absolute;
  top:-5px;
  transform:rotate(135deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(135deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(135deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(135deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(135deg);
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  right: 18px;
}

.title{
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  display:block;
  width; 100%;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="user_inbox">
  <div class="overflow">
    <span class="title">there is a title</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

or on the "bottom" (underneath the *title*);

```css
.overflow{
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  width: inherit;
  background: #cf5;
  max-height:55%;
  min-height:180px; 
}

.user_inbox{
  position:absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius:2px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #ccc;
  width:  310px;
  direction:ltr;
  left:53px;
  top:63px;
  border:1px solid #CCC;
  z-index:5000;
  /*height:100%;
  max-height:55%;
  min-height:180px; */
  right: 53px;
  top: 65px;
}
.user_inbox:after{
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 2px 0 rgba( 178, 178, 178, 0.4 );
  content: "\00a0";
  display: block;
  height: 12px;
  width:  12px;
  margin-left:18px;
  position:absolute;
  top:-5px;
  transform:rotate(135deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(135deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(135deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(135deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(135deg);
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  right: 18px;
}

.title{
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  display:block;
  width; 100%;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="user_inbox">
  <span class="title">there is a title</span>
  <div class="overflow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you .. upvote .. btw `#cf5` background color is nice :-)

Comment: @stack `#cf5` is a pupil-burner, exactly what's needed :D ;) You're welcome!

Comment: Agreed about the color :-) Just one thing, Can I wrap `div.user_inbox` element into another element instead of adding a new element like `div.overflow` into it? Because I have lots of CSS properties based on `.user_inbox > ...` name .. I can **not** change all of them ..

Comment: @stack sure you can! But than you need to `:after` (the arrow) on that non-overflow wrapper `.wrapper_user_inbox:after{` (than you can leave the `.user_wrapper` `overflow:hidden`)

Comment: @stack see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lygx0hxj/) hope it helps.